# How to avoid runtime error when using va_arg() in C

Tags: c, runtime, printf, variadic-functions

I'm trying to make some function that will do similar effect like `printf`.

Before I'm making these function I'm learning about `va_list`, `va_start`, `va_arg`...
I've made a simple code:

```
int main()
{
    success("Hello", 356);
}
void success(char* format, ...)
{
    va_list list;
    char *String;
    va_start(list,format);
    String = va_arg(list,char*);
    printf("%s",String);
    va_end(list);
    getchar();
}
```

This code **should** fail with runtime error (sending integer while expecting to get string).

I'm trying to avoid the runtime error, I want to print some error message if `va_arg` fails and exit the program but I don't know how to check if `va_arg` failed.

I've searched a solution but I couldn't find any. 
I can't use try->catch because I'm programming in C.

Comment: You can't. Not in general, not even for specific cases. (What if someone passes an integer that happens to also be the address of a string?) You're not even guaranteed a runtime error.

Comment: that's why I wrote **should**. Are you sure i can't do anything about it?

Comment: I'm not sure you can't do anything about it, but I'm pretty sure you can't do anything useful about it.

Comment: You can't, and its cited in the standard: C99899 §7.16.1.1, "...If there is no actual next argument, or if type is not compatible with the type of the actual next argument (as promoted according to the default argument promotions), **the behavior is undefined**, except for the following cases: (1) — one type is a signed integer type, the other type is the corresponding unsigned integer type, and the value is representable in both types; (2) — one type is pointer to void and the other is a pointer to a character type.

Comment: @WhozCraig there could still be a platform-specific way to do it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. Because the variable argument functions like your `success()` has no knowledge of what type of arguments it receives, not even how many arguments.

The best you can do is to use certain format specifier in the `format` parameter to provide information such as how many variable arguments and/or what type they are. And hope when this function is called, the caller would follow this law. This is what the `printf()` family functions do.

Reference: [How can I discover how many arguments a function was actually called with?](http://c-faq.com/varargs/nargs.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll try to use your idea.